# How do I call a function from my library from the build.rs file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to call a tokio main function of setup.rs as follows from build.rs in my project.
I need this to pre-install a library for my crate i.e. the setup.rs main function should get called during build of my crate.
I am unable to execute the main function of setup.rs from build.rs.

**Setup.rs:**

```
//Main function called for setup
#[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))]
#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let mut env_var_not_present = false;
//    ....Some other code here to download the requisite library and unzip the same
}
```

**Build.rs:**

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let env_var_not_present = env::var("PATH").is_err();
    let mut project_dir = String::new();
    if env_var_not_present {
        project_dir = ".".parse().unwrap();
    }else{
        project_dir = env::var("PATH").unwrap();
    }
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}/{}",project_dir,"lib"); // the "-L" flag


    #[cfg(windows)]
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=foobar");// the "-l" flag
    #[cfg(not(windows))]
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=foo"); // the "-l" flag
    
    **//HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CALL THE setup.rs main() method**
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add a lot of details as to why `setup.rs` even exists and is async for things to make sense, because at this point I can't say I see the purpose of it at all. Why don't you just... download the library (why even need to do that?) in build.rs?

Comment: My crate depends/compiles upon pre existing C library as you can see  in build.rs. Now the C library is present in an online repository. The C library can be present on rust user system or not. If not, my crate is supposed to check and download the C library for the platform i.e. Win or UNIX or MAC i.e. .dll or .so or .dylib format of the C library. This is the reason I am using build.rs. setup.py is the code which will download the C library and needs to be called before the crate installation. Hope I have given the info you were looking for.

Comment: Typo in above comment "setup.rs" not "setup.py". Currently user runs setup.rs separately to download the C library for it's platform but I want the process to be automated where user need not do anything manually. Also ASYNC is used because I am downloading the C library from over the web and downloading is an async job i.e. let response = reqwest::get(file_url).await?

Comment: reqwest has a `blocking` feature and interface, there is no reason to use async for that. And from what I've seen, most -sys or packages relying on a C library will either need the user to have installed the C library themselves, or will embed said library, possibly both (falling back to the latter if the library is not otherwise installed).

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for your help. I did some further research and figured that @Masklinn is right indeed.
Ideally, in order for the crate to compile, the C code should be pre-downloaded in the system and providing the functionality in Build.rs for the same is actually absurd.

It should ideally be packaged with the crate itself or the user should download the library and then use the crate.